# Executing multiple javascript files based on boolean conditions

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have around 5 javascript files in my WordPress website, And I tried to execute them one by one based on a boolean condition.

The javascript calls `tag1.js` if the count is 0. 
`tag2.js` if the count is 1 and so on.

If the count reaches 4, the count resets to 0. And thus this is repeated continously. I tried this code. But it doesn't work even for the first time.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function( $ ) {
   var canClick = true;
   var count= 0;
   $("body").click(function () {
       if (canClick) {
           if(parseInt(count) === 0) {
                $.getScript("https:example.com/custom_js/atag1.js");  
            }
            else if(parseInt(count) === 1) {
                $.getScript("https:example.com/custom_js/atag2.js");  
            }
            else if(parseInt(count) === 2) {
                $.getScript("https:example.com/custom_js/atag3.js");  
            }
            else if(parseInt(count) === 3) {
                $.getScript("https:example.com/custom_js/atag4.js");  
            }
            else if(parseInt(count) === 4){
                $.getScript("https:example.com/custom_js/atag5.js");
                count=0;
             }            
            canClick = false;
            setTimeout(() => {
              canClick = true
            },10000);
           count = parseInt(count)+1;
       }
    });
});
```

Basically this code executes each javascript if the user clicks on the page with timeout differentiating the clicks.

Comment: None of the `parseInt()` calls are necessary

Comment: `else if(parseInt(count)==1{` is missing the closing `)` is that a copy error?

Comment: @sibabratswain Your edit fixed a syntax error that might very well have been the source of original problem.

Comment: I just saw that syntax error, but correcting that syntax error didn't make anything right. Will try the answer below.

Comment: Oops, my bad. the syntax error corrected it, but it seems like the time difference is not calculated correctly.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to load the script as per the number of clicks. Then you can look at this solution which will look more precise.

```
var clicks = 0;
document.addEventListener('click', () => {
  loadJS();
  ++clicks;
});


function loadJS() {
  if (clicks === 4) {
     clicks = 0;
  }
  switch (clicks) {
    case 0:
        console.log('load first js');
        break;
    case 1:
        console.log('load second js');
        break;
    case 2:
        console.log('load 3rd js');
        break;
    case 3:
        console.log('load 4th js');
        break;
    case 4:
        console.log('load 5th js');
        break;
    default:
    // code block
 }
}
```

[working demo](https://codepen.io/sibabrat_swain/pen/BajojgQ?__cf_chl_jschl_tk__=4b2ba84d94ad5e0c4cbe366cde1894ae73eec10f-1591617305-0-AWFbN2OPHULUvcsBVKTgCnVg2EfjyiXkt1K07xN6ZsrI9X-SuaLiGnJUcfp6_dNG7OMvX49NwrsstREpguWkbeVPffvFMF2aHHEoBIxC6HvJlWg4i5jyDiTh5LhzGG0umubcqhgDRWtTV1uyNWH2DSgvJ-HIBswHWlFCgwe_sTxFMC9YyKXQ1Wmr1FiBFAvGZSlkxkOxP24PP1HvRvwELP0dbS9AUJPl8MvGw13lyRZ2e_93MolJm81Z-33b4Z4AybIF0RblacD4h10dbruWWCsGmwbwTAo8YsoX3ll27Xgn4jUr3MVqmTamr7s1slG-8C8mrJnKYPK7sz1MJKNYFFI)

Comment: What have you changed? And why did you do so?

Comment: So this whole code should be pasted inside `jQuery(document).ready(function( $ ) {`  and  `});`

Comment: No, I didn't want to open a js to load on every click, I neesd to set a timeout,. ie If the clicks are done within 10 seconds, then the js should not load.

Comment: @hindisong.cc yes you can add it inside tour document ready. I just have illustrated a way to do the same thing in a neat way. If you click on the working demo then you can see how it works.